# Pure CSS Tabs: absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have an already working solution for tabs with pure CSS. Now the drawback of my solution is that due to the **absolute positioning** of the actual tab content elements below will need to be moved with a margin-CSS-rule.

This leads to two major problems:

1) If the amount of content in each of the tabs varies, then if a tab with fewer content is selected, there's "unnesessary" whitespace below that tab.

2) If you resize the website to a smaller size elements might overlap.

**I prefer a solution without any javascript or jQuery, but this is not mandatory.**

An example of what i mean: Look at the two tab groups on my website:
http://alexander-pastor.de

For the drawbacks in this example to become more obvious:

1) Select a tag in the tag-tab.

2) Resize the window to a much smaller size and scroll down.

Here's the markup and the css-rules:

EDIT: do not mind the insert-tags they're from my CMS.

Markup

```
<div id="blog-wrapper">

    <div id="blog-left">
        <div id="blog-news">
            {{insert_module::55}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="blog-right">
        <ul class="tabs" style="margin-bottom:260px;">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1">
                <label for="tab1">
                    <span class="fa fa-gear"></span> 
                    <span class="tab-text">Tools</span>
                </label>
                <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
                    {{insert_article::blog-tools}}
                </div>
            </li>

            <li id="blog-authorization">
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" checked>
                <label for="tab2">
                    <span class="fa fa-user"></span> 
                    <span class="tab-text">Mein Account</span>
                </label>
                <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
                    {{insert_article::blog-authorization}}
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <br style="clear:both">

        <ul class="tabs" style="margin-bottom:1000px;">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs2" id="tab3" checked>
                <label for="tab3">
                    <span class="fa fa-tag"></span>
                    <span class="tab-text">Tags</span>
                </label>
                <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
                    <p class="reset">
                        <a href="blog.html">gewählte Tags zurücksetzen</a>
                    </p>
                    {{insert_module::60}}
                    <!-- TAGCLOUD -->
                </div>
            </li>

            <li id="blog-archive">
                <input type="radio" name="tabs2" id="tab4">
                <label for="tab4">
                    <span class="fa fa-archive"></span>
                    <span class="tab-text">Archiv</span>
                </label>
                <div id="tab-content4" class="tab-content">
                    {{insert_module::58}}
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs2" id="tab5">
                <label for="tab5">
                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                    <span class="tab-text">Empfohlen</span>
                </label>
                <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content">
                    {{insert_article::blog-featured}}
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>       
        <br style="clear:both">
    </div>  

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    top:-10px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding-left:0;
    text-align: left;
}

.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tabs label {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 21px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: rgba(220, 240, 255, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs label:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 126, 220, 0.3);
}

.tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 25px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(169, 218, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px;
}

.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  background: rgba(169, 218, 255, 0.3);
}

.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would have prefered some pure CSS-solution here's the jQuery solution to my problem:

[jQuery dynamic margin for tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364822/jquery-dynamic-margin-for-tabs)